# как сделать скрипт диалога в bash

Tags: bash, sh

```
      echo -n "сделать ? <- "
      read ACT
      echo выполняю!
```

пока я не введу ***yes*** вопрос бы *повторялся*  ,как допилить скрипт ?

Comment: while read a; do [ "$a" = yes ] && break; done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    echo -n "сделать ? <- "
    read ACT
    case $ACT in
        [Yy]es) break;;
        *) echo "'$ACT' is not 'Yes'";;
    esac
done
echo выполняю!
```

Comment: можно `echo -n "сделать ? <- "; read ACT;` заменить на `read -p "сделать [Y/N]? <-" -n1 ACT`